# approximate/polygonize a polygon from image segmentation output

Tags: image-processing, geometry, computer-vision

I have images which are building segmentations extracted from satellite images.
[image: example]

Since they are buildings, I want to process these raw output to be polygons: Decimate the curve line to be a similar 'straight' lines (fewer points curve) and get a closure outlines.
[image: example]

Any efficient algorithm to achieve that? (I don't know what's the name of this process in image processing and how to search for it.)

Comment: Do you know how to convert the segmented images into a polygonal representation, and you're asking about how to simplify the polygons themselves? Or are you asking how to generate polygons from the segmentations?

Comment: Maybe [shape detection](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) is what you're looking for

Comment: @CrisLuengo I want to know how to simplify the polygons themselves. for converting the images, I tried rasterio.features.shapes(). Not very precise but seems ok. If you have better suggestion also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Given the outline of a building as a polygon, you can simplify this polygon using the [Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) (a.k.a. Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm).

This is quite a simple algorithm to implement, but you're likely to find a ready-made implementation in your language/framework of choice.

The algorithm takes a single parameter as input, a tolerance (distance). It recursively removes points that, when removed, do not move the polygon edge by more than this parameter (actually, it works the other way around, adding back points, but the result is equivalent).

Comment: I tried it, it in general works ok. However when facing some vertexes with short edge, it will simply it to be a diagonal instead of a 90-degree angles. If with very small tolerance the line will be more squiggly

Comment: @qqxlafk: Of course. How do you distinguish squiggly line from an actual short edge? If you have a definition you can build it into the algorithm. If you expect the computer to magically know what you’re looking for, you’re out of luck.

Comment: The second image comes from Miscrosoft builiding footprint repo: https://github.com/microsoft/USBuildingFootprints . They said they didn't use the DP algorithm however didn't open theirs.... So I wonder if any other way to achieve this except for the DP algorithm

Comment: @qqxlafk: OK, so why don't you use their algorithm then? Why ask a question here if you already know how to solve this?

Comment: Cuz they didn't publish the algorithm........  Isn't stack overflow a place for discussion and learning?